# Apache/Laravel error: Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

~ Every week my Laravel website goes down with a 500 error. Restarting Apache temporary fixes it.

Initially I was getting the following error in my Laravel Logs:

```
[2018-09-18 11:31:09] production.ERROR: exception
'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
'Allowed memory size of 4194304000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
140038032930024 bytes)' in Unknown:0 Stack trace: #0 {main}
```

I updated the `memory_limit` in the `php.ini` file (and also upgraded my ec2). This made the error go away.

Now im getting `500` errors when loading the site (after a week of normal usage), and have found the following error in my `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file.

```
[Tue Oct 02 00:54:08.219442 2018] [core:notice] [pid 26736] AH00051: child pid 1068 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

A few things Ive tried.

- Clear Cache: After noticing Cached Memory was high I ran `sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, it didn't help.
- Remove non-critical PHP modules: This was hard to test and I'm unsure which modules could cause the issue. Everytime I removed a module I needed to restart apache (which would fix the issue anyway).
- Looked for Infinite Loops: I couldn't find anything in my code base that was doing this, the worst thing I could find was a page that performs 5 ajax requests on page load.

Specs

- PHP  5.5.9-1
- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- Laravel 5.2.45
- New Relic
- Apache
- PHP Modules:

  - bcmath
  - bz2
  - calendar
  - Core
  - ctype
  - curl
  - date
  - dba
  - dom
  - ereg
  - exif
  - fileinfo
  - filter
  - ftp
  - gd
  - gettext
  - hash
  - iconv
  - json
  - libxml
  - mbstring
  - mcrypt
  - memcached
  - mhash
  - mysql
  - mysqli
  - newrelic
  - openssl
  - pcntl
  - pcre
  - PDO
  - pdo_mysql
  - Phar
  - posix
  - readline
  - Reflection
  - session
  - shmop
  - SimpleXML
  - soap
  - sockets
  - SPL
  - standard
  - sysvmsg
  - sysvsem
  - sysvshm
  - tokenizer
  - wddx
  - xml
  - xmlreader
  - xmlwriter
  - Zend OPcache
  - zip
  - zlib
  - [Zend Modules]
  - Zend OPcache
- Apache Modules:

  - core_module (static)
  - so_module (static)
  - watchdog_module (static)
  - http_module (static)
  - log_config_module (static)
  - logio_module (static)
  - version_module (static)
  - unixd_module (static)
  - access_compat_module (shared)
  - alias_module (shared)
  - auth_basic_module (shared)
  - authn_core_module (shared)
  - authn_file_module (shared)
  - authz_core_module (shared)
  - authz_host_module (shared)
  - authz_user_module (shared)
  - autoindex_module (shared)
  - deflate_module (shared)
  - dir_module (shared)
  - env_module (shared)
  - filter_module (shared)
  - mime_module (shared)
  - mpm_prefork_module (shared)
  - negotiation_module (shared)
  - php5_module (shared)
  - rewrite_module (shared)
  - setenvif_module (shared)
  - socache_shmcb_module (shared)
  - ssl_module (shared)
  - status_module (shared)

Comment: Did you find the core dump? Did you look at it? See [this answer for help understanding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630915/apache-core-dump-files)

Comment: Couldn't see any dumps in the `/etc/apache2` directory. Ive just enabled the dumps (followed the instructions found in this file: `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.backtrace`). Will write back next time it Seg Faults.